# How to use ? character in an enum

Tags: c#

I work in C#, Visual Studio '05... In my enum, how can I use  the `'?'` character? My enum is
below:

```
public enum Questions
{
    How_old_are_you?_= 0,//How to set the ? character 
    What_is_your_name= 1
}
```

After I add  the `'?'` character there are some errors.

Answer (score 13):

`?` isn't a valid character in a C# identifier (including enum values). I strongly suggest you use something like:

```
public enum Question
{
    [Description("How old are you?")]
    Age,

    [Description("What is your name?")]
    Name
}
```

Or have a map or a resource file etc - just don't try to make the name of the enum into a natural language description.

**EDIT:** For reference, if you want to get at the `Description` from code, here's how to do it (thanks [Christian Hayter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115413/christian-hayter)):

```
((DescriptionAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
    typeof(Question).GetField("Age", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static), 
        typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
).Description;
```

Comment: Perhaps some code on how to get the value of the description would be in order too, since I believe this would be useful in the context of the question. (And I'm curious.)

Comment: ((DescriptionAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Question).GetField("Age", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static), typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)).Description

Comment: Thanks for the edits - I had to dash straight after writing this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. ? is an operator, so a sequence of characters containing it is not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use question marks in the enum identifiers. The identifiers in an enumeration follows the same rules as other identifiers.

You can use the @ character to use reserved keywords as identifiers, but you still can't use characters that are not allowed in an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can add q after the question to make it descriptive. Ex:

```
  How_old_are_you_q= 0,        //Replace ? with q
    What_is_your_name_q= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution could be a mix between an enum and a dictionary :

```
public enum Question
{
  Age,
  Name
}

...

Dictionary<Question,string> Questions = new Dictionary<Question,string>();

Questions.Add(Question.Age,  "How old are you ?");
Questions.Add(Question.Name, "What is your name ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tag your `Enum` items with underscore characters, which are allowed in `Enum`, and replace them for display.

Eg Binding an `Enum` to a `ComboBox`, say, replacing first "__" with "?", then "_" with space `Enum` item `How_old_are_you__` becomes `ComboBox` item "How old are you?"

I use this when I want to stick with `Enum` over other options. It works well for partially loading `Enum` items into lists and display controls as well.